# ODS file are not generating in Proc Report

Tags: sas

I am trying to generate the ODS pdf file after running the proc report syntex.

```
ods pdf file = "D:\New folder (2)\Assignment\Case_Study_1\Summary.pdf";                                                              

proc report data = Cs1.olympics headline;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
column Probability Stage (n) Total_Media_Value Tot_Forecast;                                                                            
where Probability > 0;                                                                                                               

   define Probability/group Descending 'Probability';                                                                                   
   define Stage/group noprint;                                                                                                          
   define n / format = comma6. 'Nbr_of_Optys';                                                                                          
   define Total_Media_Value/analysis format = dollar25. 'Tot_Budget';                                                                   
   define Tot_Forecast/computed format = dollar25.;                                                                                     

   compute Tot_Forecast;                                                                                                                
      if upcase (_BREAK_) = ' ' then do;                                                                                                   
         Tot_Forecast = (Total_Media_Value.sum*Probability)/100;                                                                              
         Tot_Forecast_Summer=sum(Tot_Forecast_Summer,Tot_Forecast);                                                                           
      end;                                                                                                                                 
      else do;                                                                                                                             
         Tot_Forecast=Tot_Forecast_Summer;                                                                                                    
      end;                                                                                                                                 
   endcomp;                                                                                                                             

   rbreak after / summarize ol ul;                                                                                                      

   run;          
   ods pdf close;
```

I am not able to generate the pdf. Can you please help me out.
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Can you share the ERROR, if any, that you see in the log?

Comment: Are you connected to a SAS server, or is SAS local to your PC?

Comment: SAS is local at my PC

Comment: No error was generated. Report was generated in the output not in PDF.

Comment: When you look at the log do you have the following: NOTE: ODS PDF printed X pages to D:\New folder (2)\Assignment\Case_Study_1\Summary.pdf?

Comment: PDF file generated was blank

Comment: The log shows a message ODS PDF printed no output.